# How to compare a string in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, regex, string

I have a string which will be in DB like below.

let text = "Hi {#var#}, ghkk{#Var#}"

But from user we will get the value like below.

let text2 =  "Hi xya, ghkkhoww"

It can be upto 10 variables. I want to compare both text and text2 and in place of {#var}, if some value is there, then the string is equal, else it is not. Can anybody please give me an idea how to compare this ?

Comment: I think that the best way to get an existing template engine like Mustache or EJS. A brief list of engines could be found here - https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/template-engines-for-nodejs

Comment: @vasylmoskalov Hi thank you for the response, is there any way we could do it using regex?

Comment: Yes. But I think that the usage of the existing template engines will cost less time and resources. 
But, anyway, if you want to build your own then try to look to this article https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-line

Comment: Looks like I do not clearly understand what exactly you want to do. Am I right that you need to fill variables with values from strings? I.e. you have a string 'Hi all!' and template "Hi {#user#}!" and you need to fill variable user with value 'all'?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov you have a string 'Hi all!' and template "Hi {#user#}!" and I need to compare those 2 and return a response valid or invalid..

Comment: Just convert your template to regexp

Comment: How can I create this regex and compare it with the string customer provides? I'm confused. Could you please provide more inputs? @VasylMoskalov

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways here are a few:

- String(var1).includes(var2) | Determine if var1 includes var2
- String(var1).indexOf(var2) | returns the index if var2 in var1
- String(var1).search(var2) | searches for var2 in var1 (best for paragraphs or sentences)
- String(var1).equals(var2) | do both strings equal one-another
- String(var1).compareTo(var3) | are these strings comparable
- var == var2 | do they equal **note** do not use === which is know as the equivalence operator.

As you can see its completely dependent on the use case. This is a standard problem in CS but, the common rule of thumb would be using the ==, indexOf, and equals. **SideBar** I guess you could use Regular expressions, commonly known as Regex. It's pretty powerful, with a small learning curve but, you can easily get expressions wrong and cause an edge case where your code is letting scenarios sneak by which can be difficult to find if you don't know what your looking for or how its affecting your code.

Resources:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp

Comment: The first link you give is actually Java - the author has confused Java and JavaScript.

Comment: Resource removed, but the concept is still the same